# Archer GRC Calculation based on three fields

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

[image]

```
    IF [Chemical Incident Awareness Required] = VALUEOF([Chemical Incident Awareness Required],"No")
    [Chemical Incident Awareness Status] = VALUEOF([Chemical Incident Awareness Status],"Pending")
```

I need help creating a calculation where I set the field Chemical Incident Awareness Status (a value list) to "Pending" based on if Chemical Incident Awareness Required (another value list field) is "No".

Also if Chemical Incident Awareness Date Completed is *any valid value* set Chemical Incident Awareness Status to "Completed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    IF(
    NOT(ISEMPTY([Chemical Incident Awareness Date Completed])),
        VALUEOF([Chemical Incident Awareness Status],"Completed"), IF(
    [Chemical Incident Awareness Required] = VALUEOF([Chemical Incident Awareness Required],"No"),
        VALUEOF([Chemical Incident Awareness Status],"Pending")
    )
    )
```

Hope this helps!